# How to flag a contact as being deceased in the Contacts app for iOS/macOS?

Tags: macos, contacts, metadata

Death is a sad fact of life and over the years some of my old contacts have died.

I still wish to keep a record of their details, birthday, day they died, notes, spouse, kids, etc. in my Contacts app on my iPhone, Mac, and iCloud.

I am looking for a recommended way to flag those records to indicate that the person is dead. I am interested to know how other people have dealt with this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had the same "need." I guess we all do sooner or later. Here's what I did.

Card menu > Add Field > Dates. Then select the Date field drop down in the contact and select custom.

You can also change the general new contact template in the same Cart menu.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I wish Apple had [RFC 6474](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6474) implemented in their Contacts app. You would then be able to add the place of birth, place of death and date of death to a vcard.

Answer (score 13):

As CDK suggests, my solution was adding a new custom date.

My problem was that I didn't want to be reminded with this person's birthday every year. Finally, I deleted the birthday and added a new custom date for "birth", so it's not recognized by iCal and there are no more notifications about it.

Answer (score 7):

You could also add a special symbol to the contact’s comments (I use «†», also known as [U+2020 DAGGER](http://www.decodeunicode.org/u+2020)), and then create a smart group, where the criterion is `Note` > `contains` > `†` (Alt-t).

Answer (score 1):

I'm resorting to deleting birthday, and putting it in Notes. Keeps data, doesn't remind in calendar. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can add a custom date for `deceased` and that will help you keep a record. But that doesn't flag them very well for general viewing. You can't filter by the presence or absence of your custom field (at least not in 10.7).

I would also insert a keyword in the notes to use as your filter, something like `#deceased`. Then you can set up a filtered group called `Not dead` to mask all those poor folks. And conversely a `Dead and gone` group will help you reminisce.